# Running codes from local machine on a remote linux server without loading them to the server

Tags: linux, matlab

I have a bunch of codes written in MATLAB (file.m) that I would like to run them on a remote Debian server but because of security reasons I cannot copy the code on the server. Is there anyway I can run it on the server such that nobody can access the content of the codes? I was thinking may be by referencing them (e.g. using ssh or any other way) on local machine without loading the codes to the server I can do it but I don't know how. Thanks, 
-J

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with putting the code on the server and `chmod`ing it so others can't read it?

Some other possible suggestions depending on your requirements:

- Pipe the code into a matlab process over ssh (as if you just typed it in to the interactive console). This is made much harder because matlab doesn't let you define functions at the command line.
- Mount your desktop using sshfs and run it from matlab that way.
- If you have the fancy version of the parallel computing stuff, you can start a Matlab worker process on the server and send code to it remotely, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect the sourcecode of your .m files, you can scramble them with [pcode](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/pcode.html). That way matlab will be able to execute them, but the original .m file can't be reconstructed, although bad people can still steal your .p code and execute (but not modify) it.

I don't know what kind of security you have in mind. Executing code on a server without actually transmitting the code to it sounds impossible to me. If you don't trust the remote server, you'll have to execute in on your own machine and have the server send you the data that has to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/).